# Switch values of two html select option elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a button that changes the selected options in a dropdown.

The code looks something like this:

```
<select class="select1">
<option value="1" id="firstOption">First Option</option>
<option value="2" id="secondOption">Second Option</option>
</select>

<select class="select2">
<option value="1" id="firstOption">First Option</option>
<option value="2" id="seconOption">Secon Option</option>
</select>
```

My goal is to make a button that switches out the selected options in the two `<select>`s. There is a lot more different options, so I’d be great if I were able to tell JS or jQuery to set a `var` equal to the `value` or `id` of the selected element, and then switch the selected options out, with the option with the id or value of the `var`, so that select1 has the option, that select2 had before, selected, and vise versa.

The two `<select>`s have the exact same options.

Comment: you may need to clarify your questions, as it is a little bit confusing. why would you want the button to select the same options again for the same selects?

Comment: `.selected = true`

Comment: What you're asking literally makes no sense.  You just asked if Select 1 has Option 1 and Select 2 has Option 2 to make a button select what is already selected....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution to your problem

```
<button onclick="setOptions()"></button>

function setOptions() {
    var a = $(".select1").val();
    var b = $(".select2").val();

    if((a==1 && b==2) || (a==2&&b==1))
    {
      console.log("true");
      $(".select1").val("1");
      $(".select2").val("2");
    }
    else
      console.log("false");
  }
```

But as [H H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3006589/h-h) commented, why would you want a button to select the selected options?

Comment: I think your mean if((a==1 && b==2) || (a==2 && b==1)) //two ANDs

Comment: I tried to update the question, I hope that makes a bit more sense

Comment: The question is still unclear. Are you trying to set the same options for both the selects, for ex: if select 1 has option 1 selected and select 2 has option 2 selected, then assign option 1 to both the selects or reverse the selection, assign option 2 to select 1 and option 1 to select 2

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer after a lot of fiddling (im very bad at jquery):

HTML

```
<li class="li1">
<select class="select1">
<option value="1">First Option</option>
<option value="2">Second Option</option>
</select>
</li>
<li class="li2">
<select class="select2">
<option value="1">First Option</option>
<option value="2">Second Option</option>
</select>
</li>
<button onclick="switchOptions()"></button>
```

js

```
function switchOptions(){ 
        var chFrom = $(".select1").find(":selected").val();
        var chTo = $(".select2").find(":selected").val();
        $("li.li1 select").val(chTo);
        $("li.li2 select").val(chFrom);
    }
```

thanks for trying :-)